# How to turn a comma separated string into a dictionary in which the key is an item and the value is the length of the key

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary

I'm trying to write a function that, given a string of items (stringOfItems) that are seperated by commas, creates a dictionary where each key is an item and the associated value of each key is the number of characters in that key.

Then the function should return the dictionary.

For example, given this string:

```
"bubblegum,square,puddle,abcd"
```

The function should return:

```
{'bubblegum':9,'square':5,'puddle':6,'abcd':4}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could split the elements in the string and build a dictionary with a dictionary comprehension, using each term as `key` and its `len` as `value`:

```
s = "bubblegum,square,puddle,abcd"
{i:len(i) for i in s.split(',')}
# {'bubblegum': 9, 'square': 6, 'puddle': 6, 'abcd': 4}
```

Or using a for loop:

```
d = dict.fromkeys(s.split(','))
for k in d:
    d[k] = len(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
stringOfItems = "one,two,three,sixteen"

items = stringOfItems.split(",")
myDict = {}
for i in items:
    myDict[i] = len(i)

print(myDict)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.